# intellisense not working in a cshtml template in a dll that has razorengine reference to get a model properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

HI read some articles about razorengine and I implemented the same.

https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/IntellisenseAndResharper.html
but it was not working for me.

even researched code from stackoverflow and try to work around it, but it was also not working.

Note: the answer is stackoverflow is not working for me

this is how I tried add intellisense to cshtml

```
@using RazorEngine
@using Text.Model
@inherits Templating.TemplateBase<EmailModel>
```

I had a model under folder Model with name EmailModel, I have a HTML template under Templates with name EmailTemplate

my model class

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

my goal is to write in cshtml

```
@using RazorEngine
@using Text.Model<!-- namespace-->
@inherits Templating.TemplateBase<EmailModel>

<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
   <p>
     @Model.Name
     @Model.Timestamp
   </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

but still my intellisense is showing me squiggly lines @Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is dll project so we cannot use @model to bind and get intellisense help in cshtml.

the appropriate solution to this in 2 ways

1) write a class and define a constant in that class

```
const string EmailTemplate =@"<html>
                                 <p>
                                   @model.Name is going to @model.Country
                                  </p>
                               </html>";
```

call this constant into the class where you are calling razorengine

and pass this EmailTemplate as template for razorengine and you EmailModel as model

2)write in App.config under argumnets section

```
<arguments>
    <add name="EmailBody" value="&lt;html&gt;
                                     &lt;body&gt;
                                         &lt;p&gt;
                                             @Model.Name is going to  
                                             @Model.Country*********   
                                         &lt;/p&gt;
                                     &lt;/body&gt;
                                 &lt;/html&gt;" />
<arguments/>
```

Note: html regular<> tags don't work in app.config

these two ways are working to make razorengine to create email templates in Non MVC (dll & console) applications

Answer (score 0):

> but still my intellisense is showing me squiggly lines @Model

Shouldn't that be since you are referring to `@Model` as seen in below code segment but I don't see anywhere in your `*.cshtml` you are having a `@Model` binded. Basically your view is not a *Strongly Typed View*. So there is no model and thus the error

```
   <p>
     @Model.Name
     @Model.Timestamp
   </p>
```

`@inherits` is for inheriting a base class as the linked doc in your comment say

> you can get minimal intellisense by providing **your own base class** and
>   using it with the @inherits directive.

You need to add the `@Model` directive to bind a model like

```
@model namespace.modelname
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
   <p>
     @Model.Name
     @Model.Timestamp
   </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more information see [Accessing Your Model's Data from a Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)

Comment: `@inherits Templating.TemplateBase<EmailModel>` , I think this binds Model, https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/IntellisenseAndResharper.html correct me if I am wrong. how should I bind then

Comment: This project is not a MVC, it is a dll, even your updated suggestion is not working . i.e `@model namepace.model`

Comment: I'm stumped out, tried several ways to get things done.